# Unable to remove write protection from my SD card in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, sd-card, diskpart, disk-protection

My SD card is showing:

> The disk is write protected

So I open Diskpart through the command line in Windows 7 and follow these steps:

1. To check my disk name I type:

> list disk

2. Now I select my SD card by this command

> select disk 1

3. Now I check the the permissions of SD card by this command

> det dis

Here is the read only status of my SD card.

> Current Read-only State : Yes
>
> Read-only : No

4. Now I type this command

> ```
> attributes disk clear readonly
> ```

5. Now, I check the status of SD card again, but nothing changes.

So, please tell me  how solve this issue.

Comment: How old is this SD card? Have you been using it for some time and it just recently did this?

Comment: it's three year old..

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities here:

1) The switch on an SD card does nothing more than block a little tab inside the reader from fitting into a little hole on the card (which you cover/uncover by flipping the switch).  Maybe the tab inside the reader is stuck?  Easy way to test this would be to just use another SD card and see if you get the same behavior. Or try to use this SD card in in another reader.

2) The SD card is bad.  The flash controller inside the card has a safety feature to protect your data if the flash memory wears out.  It will flip into write-protect mode at the hardware level to prevent you from using it anymore.  There's nothing you can do to fix this.  USB flash drives (most of which do not have a write-protect switch) will display this same behavior when they go bad.

It's a good thing SD cards are cheap :-)

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN THANK ME LATER ! - The Solution is hidden within **gpedit.msc**

After sifting through all the frankly useless 'help' out there ( e.g. unlock the write protect tab etc, change the registry keys etc...), it's simply a restrictive setting within Windows 7 or Windows 10.

Thank you to **top-password.com/blog/enable-or-disable-folder-options-in-windows/**  for sending me in the right direction.

Windows 10: -  User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > File Explorer

Windows 7: - User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Explorer

From the list of settings in the right hand side pane, I tweaked the Settings "Remove Security Tab" and "Prevent Access to Drives from My Computer" and then BOOM - disk write permissions returned to my SDHC Card in the Card Reader Drive, H:

Also check:  Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Removable Storage Access > Setting Removable Disks Deny Write Access (select Disabled)

[Helpful Link](https://www.top-password.com/blog/enable-or-disable-folder-options-in-windows/)